# Java - Using method indexOf for inputs

Tags: java, user-input, indexof

So, I am trying to find a specific character within an input given by the user. In this problem, the user inputs a British telephone number using the format

> (XXXX) XXX XXXX or (XXXXX) XXX XXX

where the area code is formed by the numbers within brackets, and the personal phone number is formed by the numbers after that.

Heretofore, I have tried - unsuccessfully - to use the `indexOf(String)` method to find the closing bracket within the user's input, with this being my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class L2ExerciseE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input thy number: ");

        String areaCode = number.substring(1, indexOf(")"));
        String telephoneNumber = number.substring((indexOf(")") + 1), 15);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("The area code is: " + areaCode);
        System.out.println("The telephone number: " + telephoneNumber);
    }
}
```

I guess that this problem is occurring because java uses a compiler, while **Python**, my previous language, used an interpreter, and, even though I've tried reading other answers, I'm having serious trouble understanding them.

What can I do to make my code work without over complicationg things? For the moment, we have only seen some I/O commands, arithmetic commands, basic concatenation, and some few other commands like `.substring()`, `.indexOf()`, and `.trim()`.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4):

`indexOf()` is not a stand-alone function (nothing in Java is a stand-alone function), it is a method on a `String`. You need to use `number.indexOf(")")` - you're looking for `")"` in `number`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below. Documentation of string class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)

```
String areaCode = name.substring(name.indexOf("(")+1,name.indexOf(")"));
        String personalNo = name.substring(name.indexOf(")")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex pattern:

```
String number = "(1234) 123 1234";
String pattern = "\\((\\d{4})\\) (\\d{3} \\d{4})|\\((\\d{5})\\) (\\d{3} \\d{3})";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(number);
if (m.find()) { 
    System.out.println("Found area code: " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("Found personal number: " + m.group(2));
}
```

The reason that a regex based solution might be the way to go here is that your exact number pattern may have some variety to it.  For example, a number with more than one space might still be considered valid, and this is easy to expresss in a regex.

## Demo

Answer (score 0):

There is one mistake in your code. Try this:
  String areaCode = number.substring(1, number.indexOf(")"));
  String telephoneNumber = number.substring((number.indexOf(")") + 1), 15);